# Electron :linux start at boot up system

Tags: linux, electron, autostart

This is a Electron Application for linux.

main.js

```js
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;
const browserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
let win;

function createWindow() {
    win = new browserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname : path.join(__dirname,"index.html"),
        protocol : "file",
        slashes : true ,
    }));
    win.on("closed", () => {win = null;})
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if(prcess.platform !== "darwin")
        app.quit()
});

app.on ("activate", ()=> {
    if(win == null)
        createWindow()
});
```

i start the app in linux by `npm start` .

**Problems :**

i) how to auto start it at bootup?

ii) which part of the code is to implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To autorun a file in linux on session started, create a desktop entry file (fileName.desktop)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name= app_name
Comment= comment_optional
Icon= app_icon
Exec= your file path 
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

save it  in either `/.config/autostart/` or `/etc/xdg/autostart/`

then the file will run automatically on system bootup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can programitically start an application on bootup in Linux

Alternate way would be to

1. To add a start-up script which would start the app when you login
2. Create a systemd service file which would start the application during bootup

https://www.tecmint.com/auto-execute-linux-scripts-during-reboot-or-startup/amp/

this site provides example to creating a script (https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-autorun-application-at-the-start-up-in-linux#LXSession_Autostart_File
)

this site provides example to creating a file in electron (https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/106/how-to-choose-read-save-delete-or-create-a-file-with-electron-framework)

You could manually create a file through your electron app for the first time installation and then write the script contents to the file

like

file.create( /etc/xdg/autostart/.desktop)

file.write("[Desktop Entry]

Name=LXTerminal

Type=Application

Exec=lxterminal

Terminal=false
")

or you could just use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch

if your still having problems then you could go through the auto-launch module and implement the auto start part in your code

Comment: it has module https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch , But will it work on Linux ?                I don't know how but a Electron opensource application has this feature and also works in linux . APP : https://github.com/ramboxapp/community-edition

Comment: According to that module "A Desktop Entry is created; i.e. a .desktop file is created in ~/.config/autostart/.". Which is a start-up script which you can also create

Comment: what about this github.com/ramboxapp/community-edition ?  chk its features

Comment: In all os you have to register somewhere to inform the os that these application have to started on bootup. In Linux that's either startup or through service.. The above application might have also followed either 1 of these 2 methods

Comment: can list out the ways and how?

Comment: If you want your application to auto start on login then make it create a script upon starting it for the first time

Comment: or using bash ?

Comment: like how examples would be appreciated

Comment: https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-autorun-application-at-the-start-up-in-linux. In this page navigate to autostart

Comment: These are the only option... Instead of manually creating the file make the application create the file and write to it. Like for first time installation create the file(script which is just a file with /bin/bash at top ). Upon reboot it will work as expected

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/106/how-to-choose-read-save-delete-or-create-a-file-with-electron-framework

Comment: The link doesn't have any auto run script

Comment: In bash which module used to invoke a script at bootup time

Comment: Xdg is used to start the application during login

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem.
solved it with the next piece of code.
it works for APPIMAGE only, if you need it for the standalone solution, you can use:
`const executablePath = app.getPath('exe')`
for the filePath.

```
import createDesktopShortcut from "create-desktop-shortcuts";
// ...
if (os.platform() == "linux" && process.env.APPIMAGE) {
  const shortcutsCreated = createDesktopShortcut({
    linux: { 
      filePath: process.env.APPIMAGE, 
      name: APP_NAME, 
      outputPath: "~/.config/autostart/" 
    },
  });
}
```

I am storing the desktop shortcut to the autostart...
Also, I think that if you are in runtime you can copy the icons to the destination folders and link to them